# primefaces autocomplete and it search properly. But it is not works properly

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I use primefaces autocomplete and  search properly. When I click Save ,Show this error message.

```
/entryPages/usDistributorDetails/Create.xhtml @95,71 itemLabel="#{territory.territoryName}": Property 'territoryName' not found on type java.lang.String
```

My xhtml code:

```
 <p:autoComplete id="territoryId11"
     value="#{usDistributorDetailsController.selected.territoryId}"
     completeMethod="#{usDistributorDetailsController.completeTerritory}"
     var="territory" itemLabel="#{territory.territoryName}"
     itemValue="#{territory.territoryId}"
     size="37"
     style="width: 264px" >

</p:autoComplete>
```

My Java Code:

```
public List<UsTerritory> completeTerritory(String query11) {

    List<UsTerritory> results = new ArrayList<UsTerritory>();
    List<UsTerritory> territoryListA = getJpaTerritoryController().findUsTerritoryEntities();

    for (UsTerritory abc : territoryListA) {

         if (abc.getTerritoryName().startsWith(query11)) {
            results.add(abc);
        }

    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Your current issue is caused by either of the following 
1) Class `UsTerritory` truly doesn't have a java-bean style member named `territoryName`

2.) There's a type mismatch between the backing bean bound property `usDistributorDetailsController.selected.territoryId` and the type that you're trying to coerce it to (the type being returned by the autocomplete item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to use a converter when working with POJOs. Take a look at: [Primfaces Autocomplete Pojo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompletePojo.jsf)